# How to avoid memory leak while returning char * in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, glib

I have a codebase like so in C where I have a function that needs to return a char *. Is there a way to modify this code so that I can return a char * without causing a memory leak like here? Glib is already a dependency, so I can use Glib functions too. I know the code is bad, it was written by people with physics degrees and not engineers.

```
char *func(int val) {
    char *name = malloc(300);
    if (!name) return NULL;

    switch(value) {
    case 0: 
        {
            name = "dog";
        }
        break;
   
    case 1:
        {
            name = "cat";
        }
        break;
  
    case 2:
        {
            name = "elephant";
        }
        break;

    default: 
        name = "wrong entry";
        return name;
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you think happens here; `name = "dog";` What happens to the pointer? What happens to what the pointer is pointing to? Hint: It probably is the opposite in both cases.

Comment: In this case the way to avoid it is to not allocate the memory and then immediately lose that pointer by overwriting it with a pointer to a string literal. The more general case is match every `malloc` with a `free`. If you do need the dynamic allocation for some reason, like you want to be able to modify the contents, then you should use `strcpy` to copy the data or perhaps `strdup` is it is available.

Comment: `name = "dog";` — `strcpy(name, "dog");`. In C you **cannot copy a string** with `=`.

Comment: @PlsBuffMyBrain Just do not allocate memory: char *name;. That is all.:)

Comment: For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330113/how-to-copy-data-to-a-pointer-returned-by-malloc

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a very basic misunderstanding of strings. You've dynamically allocated a block of memory for 300 `char` values. What you get back from `malloc` is *not* a dynamically allocated array, but rather a pointer to the first element in that dynamically allocated array.

When you assign to the pointer variable, it's no longer pointing to that chunk of dynamically allocated memory, but rather to a string literal. You no longer have any way to get back to that dynamically allocated memory. You cannot free it, so it is leaked.

You can either properly copy a string value into that memory with `strcpy` (or `strncpy`).

```
char *func(int val) {
    char *name = malloc(300);
    if (!name) return NULL;

    switch(value) {
    case 0: 
        strcpy(name, "dog");
        break;
   
    case 1:
        strcpy(name, "cat");
        break;
  
    case 2:
        strcpy(name, "elephant");
        break;

    default: 
        strcpy(name, "wrong entry");
    }

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the case in your actual code, but in this example, you don't need to return an allocated string, because all of the possible return values are string literals. String literals are stored in static data and don't need to be freed.

```c
const char *func(int val) {
    switch(value) {
    case 0: return "dog";
    case 1: return "cat";
    case 2: return "elephant";
    default: return "wrong entry";
}
```

If *not* all the strings are literals in the real code, then since you are using GLib, consider using some of its string manipulation functions that already return an allocated buffer of the correct size, so you don't have to allocate the buffer yourself and risk a buffer overflow. For example: `g_strdup_printf()`, `g_strconcat()`.

```c
char *func(int val) {
    switch(value) {
    case 0: return g_strdup("dog");
    case 1: return g_strdup("cat");
    case 2: return g_strdup("elephant");
    default: return g_strdup_printf("unknown entry %d", val);
}
```