# Proper memory free for pointers inside struct C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I have a `struct list`  which contains a dynamic array of type `struct pair`, and each element of this array points to two variable of type `struct element`. In the main
of my program I allocate, via a malloc call, memory for `struct pair pairs` array and
for each element pointer. Then I assign a value to elements, check the value and free the memory. Here is the code

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

struct element{
  int i;
};

struct pair{
  struct element *element1, *element2;
};

struct list{
  struct pair *pairs;
};

int main(void) {

  // declare variable my_list
  struct list my_list;

  // set size of pairs array (one for the example)
  my_list.pairs = (struct pair*)malloc(sizeof(struct pair));

  // set element1 and element2 of pairs[0]
  struct element element1 = {.i = 1};
  struct element element2 = {.i = 2};
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;

  // check element values
  printf("elements are: %d %d\n", my_list.pairs[0].element1->i, my_list.pairs[0].element2->i); 

  // free memory
  free(my_list.pairs);

  return 0;
}
```

I can compile and run the code without problems but if I run the code in valgrind I get the following memory leak:

```
*** valgrind --leak-check=full -s ./a.out 
==6676== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6676== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6676== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6676== Command: ./a.out
==6676== 
elements are: 1 2
==6676== 
==6676== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6676==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==6676==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 1,048 bytes allocated
==6676== 
==6676== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==6676==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6676==    by 0x1091EE: main (foo.c:27)
==6676== 
==6676== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==6676==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6676==    by 0x1091FF: main (foo.c:28)
==6676== 
==6676== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6676==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==6676==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6676==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6676==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6676==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6676== 
==6676== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Lines 27 and 28 are responsible of the leak. If I try to add (before line 36), something like `free(my_list.pairs[0].element1);` I get the following error in valgrind

```
==6684== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==6684== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6684==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6684==    by 0x10924F: main (foo.c:36)
==6684==  Address 0x1ffefff918 is on thread 1's stack
==6684==  in frame #1, created by main (foo.c:16)
```

So my questions are:

- how can I avoid the memory leak and properly free the memory allocated by lines 27 and 28?
- why trying to free the pointer `my_list.pairs[0].element1` rise the error `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()`?

Code has been compiler with gcc as follow: `gcc -Wall -g foo.c` and my version of gcc is

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `my_list.pairs[0].element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));` followed by `my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;` will overwrite the pointer. It's a similar situation to `int a; a = 10; a = 5;` You replace the value of the variable, and loose the original value.

Comment: Aside: do not cast the result of `malloc`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330113/how-to-copy-data-to-a-pointer-returned-by-malloc

Comment: It would be a simpler and faster executing collection of data types if you just ditch malloc and use plain struct variables instead of pointers.

Comment: @Lundin thank you for the comment. This code is just the minimal set of instruction to reproduce the problem I had with the longer version of the code. I need to have a pointer structure since the code is reading a file containing connections between points (STL format) and I do not know the number of points and connection in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here your program is leaking memory:

```
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;
```

reason is - `my_list.pairs[0].element1` and `my_list.pairs[0].element2` are holding the reference of memory allocated dynamically and after the above assignment, they lose those memory references. Hence, resulting in memory leak.

Note that, in your code, `element1` and `element2` are not the dynamically allocated objects. They are the objects created on the stack:

```
struct element element1 = {.i = 1};   
struct element element2 = {.i = 2};
```

It's not valid to `free` them:

```
free(my_list.pairs[0].element1);
```

`free` can only be used for pointers allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `aligned_alloc()` or `realloc()`, otherwise it will result in undefined behavior.

To fix this problem either don't allocate memory to `my_list.pairs[0].element1` and `my_list.pairs[0].element2` dynamically or allocate them dynamically and `free` them once you are done with them. Implementation of later suggestion:

```
  struct element * element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  struct element * element2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  element1->i = 1;
  element2->i = 2;
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = element1;
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = element2;

  // check element values
  printf("elements are: %d %d\n", my_list.pairs[0].element1->i, my_list.pairs[0].element2->i); 

  // free memory
  free(my_list.pairs[0].element1);
  free(my_list.pairs[0].element2);
```

Additional:

Follow good programming practice, make sure to check the returned value of `malloc()`.

Comment: ```struct element element1``` and ```struct element element2``` are static object, I agree. But ```my_list[0].pairs.element1``` and  ```my_list[0].pairs.element2``` are pointer dynamically allocated. Hence, I would expect that ```free``` them should be a valid operation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @fdv `my_list[0].pairs.element1` and `my_list[0].pairs.element2` loose the dynamically allocated memory references after these assignments - `my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;` and `my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;`. You are allocating memory to them dynamically and just after that, you are assigning them address of object created on stack.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory leak is here:

```
my_list.pairs[0].element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
my_list.pairs[0].element2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1; // overwrite of my_list.pairs[0].element1 --> memory leak
my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2; // overwrite of my_list.pairs[0].element2 --> memory leak
```

Solution:

**Option 1**

Delete the two lines doing `malloc`.

```
struct element element1 = {.i = 1};
struct element element2 = {.i = 2};
my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;
my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;
```

**Option 2**

Delete the lines creating and using local variables.

```
my_list.pairs[0].element1 = malloc(sizeof(struct element));
my_list.pairs[0].element2 = malloc(sizeof(struct element));
my_list.pairs[0].element1->i = 1;
my_list.pairs[0].element2->i = 2;

....
....

free(my_list.pairs[0].element1);
free(my_list.pairs[0].element2);
```

note: In C you don't need to cast the value returned by `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

These statements

```
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;
```

produce memory leaks.

At first memory was allocated and its addresses were assigned to pointers `my_list.pairs[0].element1` and `my_list.pairs[0].element2` and then the pointers were reassigned with addresses of local variable `element1` and `element2`

```
  // set element1 and element2 of pairs[0]
  struct element element1 = {.i = 1};
  struct element element2 = {.i = 2};
```

So the addreses of the allocated memory were lost.

Instead of using this assignment

```
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = &element1;
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = &element2;
```

you should write

```
  *my_list.pairs[0].element1 = element1;
  *my_list.pairs[0].element2 = element2;
```

to copy values of `element1` and `element2` in the allocated memory.

To free correctly the allocated memory you need to free it in the reverse order. That is

```
free( my_list.pairs[0].element1 );
free( my_list.pairs[0].element2 );
free( my_list.pairs );
```

As for your code then this statement

```
  // free memory
  free(my_list.pairs);
```

frees only the first allocated extent of memory while you allocated three extents of memory

```
  my_list.pairs = (struct pair*)malloc(sizeof(struct pair));
  //...
  my_list.pairs[0].element1 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  my_list.pairs[0].element2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```

Answer (score -1):

At this point you have some good answers as for why you have a memory leak, but I will leave here an example of a way of *creating* this type of things that can be useful. Or ignored. :)

**From the original code:**

I changed `element1` for `el1` for clarity. Also `el2`.

```
    my_list.pairs[0].el1 =  (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    my_list.pairs[0].el2 =  (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    my_list.pairs[0].el1 = &el1;
    my_list.pairs[0].el2 = &el2;
```

After reordering the lines:

```
    my_list.pairs[0].el1 =  (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    my_list.pairs[0].el1 = &el1;

    my_list.pairs[0].el2 =  (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    my_list.pairs[0].el2 = &el2;
```

And it makes clear that as soon the 2nd and 4th line runs each area returned from `malloc` is gone for good, since in each case the single pointer for the area was overwritten.

Also

```
    // declare variable my_list
    struct list my_list;
```

Maybe you could avoid this type of comment. It is clear what the declaration does.

### The example

We have here a list of pairs. Could be implemented as an array, as a linked list, as a dictionary... [*java*  has `Pair` as of Key and Value things](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javafx/util/Pair.html), and [*C++* has `pair` of `first` and `second` in *std::pair*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) as examples. And could be a list of a list of strings. Any 3-level hierarchy of things.

I will show you a way of writing this, using encapsulation, and viewing your pairs and list more like objects. It can be more productive doing so, as it uses a lot of copy and paste and simply reuses things from these other languages and (also important) form one `struct` to the other.

### The hierarchy: a list of elements in pairs

We will use `List` like a simple array of pointers, of fixed capacity. It can be implemented in any other way, like using a linked list or a simple array. But a list is just it: **a (possibly empty) collection of things**. In this case, pairs of something. For the `List` it makes no difference what *something* is. This is in essence *encapsulation*. Here, note that list makes no reference to `Element` and references `Pairs` only as an opaque object.

#### The list `List`

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include "pair.h"

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    Pair** pair;
} List;

List* make_list(size_t);
List* delete_list(List*);
int   insert_list(Pair*, List*);
int   show_list(List*, const char*);

#endif // LIST_H
```

So a list has inside it the values for its actual size and capacity. The functions, called *methods* in other languages, makes no reference to elements. Even the `Pair` could have been abstracted, using a generic name line `Info` or `Node`.

- `make_list` returns a pointer to a new empty list with the requested capacity
- `delete_list` destroys a list and return `NULL`. Why? This is so we can delete a `List` and invalidate its pointer at the same time, for safety.
- `insert_list` does the expected: inserts a record into a list. In this case a `Pair`
- `show_list` shows on-screen the elements of the list. To save a few `printf` calls, a prefix message can be added.

This is like a constructor, a destructor and a *toString* or *serialize* method in other places/languages. Only pointers are used. It is easier.

#### A possible implementation for `List.c`

```
#include "list.h"

List* make_list(size_t size)
{
    List* one = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->limit = size;
    one->size  = 0;
    one->pair  = (Pair**)malloc(size * sizeof(Pair*));
    if (one->pair == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    return one;
}

List* delete_list(List* L)
{
    if (L == NULL) return NULL;
    fprintf(
        stderr, "\n    deleting %llu elements list\n",
        L->size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < L->size; i += 1)
        delete_pair(L->pair[i]);
    free(L);
    return NULL;
}

int insert_list(Pair* p, List* l)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (l == NULL) return -2;
    if (l->size == l->limit) return -3;
    Pair* pair       = make_pair(p->first, p->second);
    l->pair[l->size] = pair;
    l->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

int show_list(List* L, const char* msg)
{
    if (L == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "[%llu/%llu] element(s) in list\n", L->size,
        L->limit);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < L->size; i += 1)
        show_pair(L->pair[i], NULL);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### The pair in `Pair.h`

```
#ifndef PAIR_H
#define PAIR_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "el1.h"

typedef struct
{
    Element* first;
    Element* second;
} Pair;

Pair* delete_pair(Pair*);
Pair* make_pair(Element*, Element*);
int   show_pair(Pair*, const char*);
#endif // PAIR_H
```

Here we have the `C++` naming for pairs: elements are `first` and `second`. *java*  uses `K` and `V` for key and value.

- `make_pair` returns a `Pair` with the provided elements.
- `show_pair` does as expected.
- `delete_pair` frees a pair and return `NULL`.

These are just copied from `List` and adapted. Only pointers are used.

#### A possible implementation for `Pair.c`

```
#include "pair.h"
Pair* delete_pair(Pair* gone)
{
    if (gone == NULL) return NULL;
    delete_el(gone->first);
    delete_el(gone->second);
    free(gone);
    return NULL;
}

Pair* make_pair(Element* a, Element* b)
{
    if (a == NULL) return NULL;
    if (b == NULL) return NULL;
    Pair* one = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->first  = copy_el(a);
    one->second = copy_el(b);
    return one;
}

int show_pair(Pair* p, const char* msg)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("  [");
    show_el(p->first, NULL);
    printf(",");
    show_el(p->second, NULL);
    printf("]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### The elements, at last

Here is where things are customized. I will use 2 `Element`:

```
typedef struct
{
    int i;
} Element;
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    int   code;
} Element;
```

The first is the same as in the question. The second is just to show that an `Element` can allocate memory, can have pointers inside, so we can not just copy its value inside a `Pair`.

So, in order to `Pair` handle such contents the user needs to provide the methods. Doing so `Pair` --- and `List` --- go unchanged from program to program like in other languages. `pair.h` has an `#include` for the `Element` header.

This is what we do in `qsort` providing the compare function, so the code can sort anything.

The reference to `Element` could be done in other smarter ways, but this here is just a toy to show how to build these things fast, so an `#include` is used.

**The functions needed for `Element`**

```
Element* copy_el(Element*);
Element* delete_el(Element*);
int      show_el(Element*, const char*);
```

It is almost the same as for the other *"classes"*:

- `copy_el` is the *copy constructor*, and it is all we need to insert an element in a `List`: it returns the address of a copy of the element, so it is owned by the list and can be inserted at a `Pair`
- `delete_el` is the destructor, since the `Element` can have complex allocation issues.
- `show_el` is a method to display on-screen an `Element`

#### an example using `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(void)
{
    Element* one     = make_el(42);
    Element* other   = make_el(-42);
    Pair*    my_pair = make_pair(one, other);
    delete_el(one);
    delete_el(other);

    show_pair(my_pair, "test_pair is ");
    List* my_list = make_list(5);  // capacity = 5
    show_list(my_list, "\n(list still empty) ");
    while (0 == insert_list(my_pair, my_list)) {};
    show_list(
        my_list, "\n(list now filled with same pair) ");
    my_pair = delete_pair(my_pair);  // free test_pair
    my_list = delete_list(my_list);  // free list
    return 0;
}
```

- `make_el` is just a helper to create an `Element` in these examples. The container only needs to know how to copy one, not how to *create* one.

This program

- creates a `Pair`
- creates a ' `List` of 5 elements
- fills the list with this pair, since the contents are irrelevant here.
- shows the list on-screen
- `free`'s everithing

#### output

```
test_pair is   [42,-42]

(list still empty) [0/5] element(s) in list


(list now filled with same pair) [5/5] element(s) in list
  [42,-42]
  [42,-42]
  [42,-42]
  [42,-42]
  [42,-42]


    deleting 5 elements list
```

#### a simple implementation for the trivial `Element`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int i;
} Element;

Element* copy_el(Element*);
Element* delete_el(Element*);
Element* make_el(const int);
int      show_el(Element*, const char*);

Element* copy_el(Element* orig)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    Element* one = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->i = orig->i;
    return one;
}

Element* delete_el(Element* orig)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    free(orig);
    return NULL;
}

Element* make_el(const int value)
{
    Element* one = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->i = value;
    return one;
}

int show_el(Element* el, const char* msg)
{
    if (el == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d", el->i);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, `make_el` is here just for the example. The container --- any one --- does not create an element in itself. It just copy one when needed and destroy when needed.

### an `Element` using a `struct` that allocates memory

**This is an example that has a pointer inside and allocates memory. It can be used the same way since the user provides a *copy constructor*.**

#### `main` for this case

Here `make_el` is of course different, but this is just for the example. `List` does not see this and `Pair` does not create elements, just copy them. Sure the user of a `List` of `MagicStuff` has some items to manage, and knows how to do it. As long as `copy_el` works, it is ok to 'List'. As long as `show_el` works `List` can do their job.

In fact pointers to these functions could be added to `List` and we would have something closer to *C++*.

Only the first five lines are different, since we need to build a pair of elements. The rest of the code is the same. The more important is the idea that the code for `Pair` and `List` is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(void)
{
    Element* one     = make_el("Stack", 42);
    Element* other   = make_el("Overflow", -42);
    Pair*    my_pair = make_pair(one, other);
    delete_el(one);
    delete_el(other);
    show_pair(my_pair, "test_pair is ");

    List* my_list = make_list(5);  // capacity = 5
    show_list(my_list, "\n(list still empty) ");

    while (0 == insert_list(my_pair, my_list)) {};
    show_list(
        my_list, "\n(list now filled with same pair ");

    my_pair = delete_pair(my_pair);  // free test_pair
    my_list = delete_list(my_list);  // free list
    return 0;
}
```

#### outout for this example

```
test_pair is   [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]

(list still empty) [0/5] element(s) in list


(list now filled with same pair [5/5] element(s) in list
  [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]
  [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]
  [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]
  [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]
  [ ("Stack",42), ("Overflow",-42)]


    deleting 5 elements list
```

#### a simple implementation for the non-trivial `Element`

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    int   code;
} Element;

Element* copy_el(Element*);
Element* delete_el(Element*);
int      show_el(Element*, const char*);

Element* copy_el(Element* orig)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    Element* one = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->name = malloc(1 + strlen(orig->name));
    if (one->name == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(one->name, orig->name);
    one->code = orig->code;
    return one;
}

Element* delete_el(Element* orig)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    free(orig->name);
    free(orig);
    return NULL;
}

int show_el(Element* el, const char* msg)
{
    if (el == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(" (\"%s\",%d)", el->name, el->code);
    return 0;
}

Element* make_el(const char* name, const int code)
{
    if (name == NULL) return NULL;
    Element* one = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->name = malloc(1 + strlen(name));
    if (one->name == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(one->name, name);
    one->code = code;
    return one;
}```

### A note on *encapsulation* ###

Here in `insert_list` a pair is inserted
```C
    Pair* pair       = make_pair(p->first, p->second);
````

but the code to do it come from `Pair` implementation.

But there in `make_pair`

```
    one->first  = copy_el(a);
    one->second = copy_el(b);
```

We see that the user-provided copy creator is used.

#### a note on building this

- Each level of *container* adds in general a pair of files, a `.h` header and the implementation file `.c`.
- Each level sees only the one below and the code is just copied and adapted
- Is is normal to have a constructor, a destructor, a copy constructor, a print function, declared as here or following some pattern. It works fine in general, since is what is done in other fields and languages.

code and a visual studio project are available at [GitHub on this link](https://github.com/ARFNetoOnSO/soc23-1030-pair)

Comment: So many fragments, but no example code provided for the `*_el()` functions... And, when requirements change in the future to store `Element* third;`, the coder will regret impressing the current "pair-ish-ness" on so many function names and even file names... Glad not to be that guy!!

Comment: @Fe2O3 this is funny! I forgot to paste those in :) Thanks for pointing that! As for the code and names, It is not that hard to understand what I explained. It is implemented like *java* or *C++* *containers, from outside in. And here there are just 2 levels. And the names are the same...

Comment: "Funny?" Funny is posting such a long answer promulgating the OP's short-sightedness naming a struct `pair` and its member `pairs`. You've renamed the OP's `element1` & `element2` to be `first` and `second`. Thus, the names of your datatypes, functions and even files and header guards are bound up with "pair". My question: What happens to those items when `first` and `second` are to be joined by `third`? Three struct members are not a "pair". Changes to the Makefile, too! Lots to go wrong when making changes! Funny...

Comment: @Fe2O3 change `Pair` to any other thing requires just doing again what I explained: copy `Pair`and rewrite constructor, destructor, copy construtor and print. The expected since it is a new *class*. Then change the `insert` function on the container above to point to the new one. It has been working well in many languages. `first` and `second` as I said are the names used in `C++`.

Comment: C is not C++. And, why doesn't `copy_el()` simply call `make_el()` to reduce code duplication?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Please understand that `make_el`  is just for the example. Again you are missing the point: for the user of `List` and `Pair` `make_el` is not available. I already explained it to you in another answer. In order to contain the element just a *`copy constructor`* is needed. `make_el` is here just because it is an example, a mock up, a proof of concept. As for using the `C++` names and ideas, well, my free example. And I like `C++`.