# How to debug this C code using threads, and how to fix the issue

Tags: c, multithreading, mergesort

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void display(int *arr, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void display2(int *arr, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        
    printf("\n");
}


void mergeA(int* arr, int lb, int ub, int mid) {
//  printf("Inside mergeA\n");
    int i=lb, j=mid+1, k=lb;
    int newarr[1000];

    while(i<=mid && j<=ub) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j])
            newarr[k++] = arr[j++];
        else
            newarr[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    
    for(; i<=mid; i++)
        newarr[k++] = arr[i];
    for(; j<=ub; j++)
        newarr[k++] = arr[j];

    for(i=lb; i<=ub; i++)
        arr[i] = newarr[i];
}
void mergeD(int* arr, int lb, int ub, int mid) {
//  printf("Inside mergeD\n");
    int i=lb, j=mid+1, k=lb;
    int newarr[1000];

    while(i<=mid && j<=ub) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[j])
            newarr[k++] = arr[j++];
        else
            newarr[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    
    for(; i<=mid; i++)
        newarr[k++] = arr[i];
    for(; j<=ub; j++)
        newarr[k++] = arr[j];

    for(i=lb; i<=ub; i++)
        arr[i] = newarr[i];
}


void mergeSortA(int* arr, int lb, int ub) {
//  printf("Inside mergeSortA\n");
    if(lb<ub) {
        int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        mergeSortA(arr, lb, mid);
        mergeSortA(arr, mid+1, ub);
        mergeA(arr, lb, ub, mid);
    }
}

void mergeSortD(int* arr, int lb, int ub) {
//  printf("Inside mergeSortD\n");
    if(lb<ub) {
        int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        mergeSortD(arr, lb, mid);
        mergeSortD(arr, mid+1, ub);
        mergeD(arr, lb, ub, mid);
    }
}

void* sort_a(void* args) {
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
    arr = (int*)args;
    int size = arr[0];

    printf("Inside Sort A: ");
    display2(arr, size);
    
    mergeSortA(arr, 1, size-1);
    printf("After Sort A: ");
    display2(arr, size);
    pthread_exit((void*)arr);
}

void* sort_d(void* args) {
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
    arr = (int*)args;
    int size = arr[0];

    printf("Inside Sort D: ");
    display2(arr, size);
    
    mergeSortD(arr, 1, size-1);
    printf("After Sort D: ");
    display2(arr, size);
    pthread_exit((void*)arr);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    int arr[1000];
    int i=0, j, k1=1, k2=1;

    //Taking the array as input
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter an element or 'quit' to stop input: ");
        
        char input[100];
        scanf("%s", input);

        if(strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
            break;

        arr[i++] = atoi(input);
    }
    printf("The Array:\n");
    display(arr, i);

    //Spliting the array into two
    int arr1[1000], arr2[1000];
    for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if(j<i/2)
            arr1[k1++]=arr[j];
        else
            arr2[k2++]=arr[j];
    }
    //Storing size in index 0
    arr1[0] = k1;
    arr2[0] = k2;

    //Creating the threads
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &sort_a, (void*)arr1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &sort_d, (void*)arr2);

    //Joining the threads
    pthread_join(t1, (void*)arr1);
    pthread_join(t2, (void*)arr2);

    //After Sorting
    printf("Main Thread:\n");
    display2(arr1, k1);
    display2(arr2, k2);
}
```

I want the output to be the same as in the functions (sort_a and sort_d) but the element in the first index is always a garbage value.
NOTE: First index in this case is 1 as I have stored the length in the 0th index

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm661.png)

As you can see the output in the main thread is not correct.

Comment: There is some good debugging advice at this link:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please create a [mcve] (note: minimal). Also, post the output as text, formatted in a code block; not as an image.

Comment: `pthread_join(t1, (void*)arr1)` will overwrite the first two (assuming 64-bit arch) ints in your array with the result. You're not checking the result, so consider storing it somewhere else.

Comment: `int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1000); arr = (int*)args;` [Here we go again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330113/how-to-copy-data-to-a-pointer-returned-by-malloc).

Comment: "NOTE: First index in this case is 1 as I have stored the length in the 0th index": while convenient, it's generally not a good idea to go against standard usage in a language. This will get confusing very fast, causing awkward mistakes.

Comment: For debugging, don't use threads. Call the functions normally instead. And use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);` Do you understand why the type of the second argument is `void**` and not `void*`?

Comment: The thread joining with `pthread_join(t1, (void*)arr1)` will not work as you probably expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be passing as a parameter the merge sub-array `arr` to `pthread_exit()` in the sort functions running as threads. Per the POSIX thread spec function prototypes pasted below, `pthread_exit()` terminates the calling thread and makes the value `value_ptr` available to any successful join with the terminating thread. The `pthread_join()` function suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates. On return from a successful `pthread_join()` call with a non-NULL parameter `value_ptr` argument, the value passed to `pthread_exit()` by the terminating thread shall be made available in the location referenced by `value_ptr`.

```
void pthread_exit(void *value_ptr);
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);
```

In `main()` you should get the value from `pthread_exit()` in the following way:

```
int main() {
  ...
  ...
  int *result1=0;
  int *result2=0;
  ...
  ...
  pthread_join(t2, (void **) &result2);
  pthread_join(t1, (void **) &result1);
  ...
  printf ("\nstatus returned thread t1=%d", *result1);
  printf ("\nstatus returned thread t2=%d", *result2);
  ...
}
```

In your sort functions, set `value_ptr` like below. Do not reference a local /stack variable for the `pthread_exit()` call parameter `value_ptr`.

```
void * sort_d(void * args) {
  ...
  int *retval;
  retval = (int *) (malloc (sizeof (int));
  ...
  *retval = 0; // any value you want to return
  pthread_exit(retval);
}
```

Alternatively you could issue a return the `value_ptr` in your sort function instead of calling `pthread_exit()`. Like below, since the return value `retval` of the sort function also serves as the exit value of the thread:

```
void * sort_d(void * args) {
  ...
  int *retval;
  retval = (int *) (malloc (sizeof (int));
  ...
  *retval = 0 // set to any value you want to return
  return retval;
}
```

The pthread functions `pthread_create()`, `pthread_join()` return zero if successful. You may want to check the return value from those functions for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

In MergeD, the compare should be:

```
        if(arr[i] > arr[j])    /* not if(arr[i] < arr[j]) */
```

sort_a and sort_d malloc arrays, but never release them. They should free the allocated memory. Both merge functions should use malloc instead of using local arrays of size 1000 so that a larger array could be sorted.

After the two threads complete, a final merge is needed.

---

There is no need to have a separate set of functions for the two threads.

As an alternative to using index 0 for the size of the array, the pthread_create could pass a pointer to a structure as an argument, where the structure would contain a pointer to an element in the array, and a size.