The Data Inside C++ Vector Changes when I use push_back()
I wrote a C++ function that uses the recursive_directory_iterator to get information on all files and folders within the parent folder. I then wrote a class called DataFolder to store each file's attributes such as file size, path, name, datenum, etc. Finally, I used a vector object to store a collection of DataFolder objects.
For the vector object I use push_back to add the DataFolder objects. The first assignment works, however on subsequent attempts the assignments are made without memory or access issues, but the data contained in all of the previously stored items are corrupted. Only the most recent addition is unchanged.
How do I add DataFolder objects to my C++ STL vector object and preserve the data previously stored within the vector?
This is the function I created: directory_base.
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include "CDir.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

// CDIR List folder.
// CDIR NAME lists the files in a folder.NAME must be specified as a
// character vector or string scalar.
//
// NAME can include a relative path, but the relative path must be in the
// current folder.Otherwise, NAME must include a full path.
//
// To list filesand folders at a remote location, NAME must contain a
// full path specified as a uniform resource locator(URL).
//
// Pathnamesand asterisk wildcards may be used in NAME.A single asterisk
// in the path touching only file separators will represent exactly one
// folder name.A single asterisk at the end of an input will represent
// any filename.An asterisk followed or preceded by characters will
// resolve to zero or more characters.A double asterisk can only be used
// in the path and will represent zero or more folder names.It cannot
// touch a character other than a file separator.For example, DIR* .m
// lists all files with a.m extension in the current folder.DIR*/*.m
//   lists all files with a .m extension exactly one folder under the
//   current folder. CDIR **/* .m lists all files with a.m extension zero or
// more folders under the current folder.
//
// D = CDIR('NAME') returns the results in an M - by - 1
// structure with the fields :
// name        -- Filename
// folder      -- Absolute path
// date        -- Modification date
// bytes       -- Number of bytes allocated to the file
// isdir-- 1 if name is a folder and 0 if not
// datenum     -- Modification date as a MATLAB serial date number.
// This value is locale - dependent.
//
// See also WHAT, CD, TYPE, DELETE, LS, RMDIR, MKDIR, DATENUM.

// Copyright 1984 - 2019 The MathWorks, Inc.
// Built - in function.

static const char* convertIntToMonth(int imon)
{
    if (imon == 1)
    {
        return "Jan";
    }
    else if (imon == 2)
    {
        return "Feb";
    }
    else if (imon == 3)
    {
        return "Mar";
    }
    else if (imon == 4)
    {
        return "Apr";
    }
    else if (imon == 5)
    {
        return "May";
    }
    else if (imon == 6)
    {
        return "Jun";
    }
    else if (imon == 7)
    {
        return "Jul";
    }
    else if (imon == 8)
    {
        return "Aug";
    }
    else if (imon == 9)
    {
        return "Sep";
    }
    else if (imon == 10)
    {
        return "Oct";
    }
    else if (imon == 11)
    {
        return "Nov";
    }
    else if (imon == 12)
    {
        return "Dec";
    }
    else if (imon < 1 || imon > 12)
    {
        return "OOR";
    }

    return "INV";
}

static double dateNumber(double year, int month, double day)
{
    double cumdays[] = { 0, 0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334 };
    double retval = 365 * year + cumdays[month] + day;
    retval += year / 4;
    return retval;
}

const vector<DataFolder>& directory_base(const char* path, vector<DataFolder>& datfldr)
{
    int ii = 0;
    
    cout << "Let put out the files!" << endl;
    for (recursive_directory_iterator i(path), end; i != end; ++i)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path()))
        {
            if (is_regular_file(i->path()))
            {
                DataFolder df{};
                filesystem::path df_name = i->path();
                string fn = df_name.string();
                df.name = new char[fn.length()];
                df.name = const_cast<char*>(fn.c_str());
                struct stat attrib {};
                struct tm *clock = new tm();
                stat(df.name, &attrib);
                errno_t errNo = localtime_s(clock, &(attrib.st_mtime));
                size_t fsz = file_size(df.name);
                df.bytes = static_cast<int>(file_size(df_name));
                
                string tmp = to_string(clock->tm_mday) + "-" + 
                convertIntToMonth(clock->tm_mon+1) + "-" + to_string(clock->tm_year+1900) + " 
                " + to_string(clock->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string(clock->tm_min) + ":" + 
                to_string(clock->tm_sec);

                df.date = new char[tmp.length()];
                df.date = const_cast<char*>(tmp.c_str());
                
                df.datenum = dateNumber(static_cast<double>(clock->tm_year)+1900, clock-
                >tm_mon+1, clock->tm_mday);

                filesystem::path df_fldr = i->path().parent_path();
                string ffldr = df_fldr.string();
                df.folder = new char[ffldr.length()];
                df.folder = const_cast<char*>(ffldr.c_str());
                df.isdir = false;
                
                cout << i->path().filename() << "\n";
                
                cout << "\nData Folder Values" << endl;
                cout << "df.name:       " << df.name << endl;
                cout << "df.date:       " << df.date << endl;
                cout << "df.bytes:      " << df.bytes << endl;
                cout << "df.datenum:    " << df.datenum << endl;
                cout << "df.folder:     " << df.folder << endl;
                cout << "df.df.isdir:   " << df.isdir << endl;
                datfldr.push_back(df);
            }
        }
    }

    return datfldr;
}

I expect the data to appear like this:

Instead, I got this:


You're doing a bunch of manual memory management in DataFolder and breaking the principle of encapsulation by doing this outside of the class. It's possibly a Rule of Three violation, depending on whether this class is deleting its memory in the destructor. There may be other issues. You should show how this class is implemented.

The problem here is likely to be your handling of df.folder.  You allocate a char array and assign it to df.folder, then on the next line you take the pointer from ffldr and store than in df.folder.  That causes your new to leak, AND it means df.folder is pointing to stack contents that will evaporate.

As above (jinx!). You begin by allocating memory that is too small to hold these strings, which itself is a problem. But then leak them by replacing the pointer with a temporary. It's really a disaster. This is not how to copy strings. You must allocate enough to include the null terminator and then use strncpy. Why are you not storing std::string members in your class? If you did that, all these problems would disappear.

Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330113/how-to-copy-data-to-a-pointer-returned-by-malloc

df.name = new char[fn.length()]; -- This is the old "the library uses pointers, so let me drive off the cliff and use pointers to" error.  As mentioned, your DataFolder class should be using std::string.  Just because the internal library exposes char * doesn't mean your own classes must follow suit and do the same thing.

This is a horrible mix of wrong C with C++. You don't need pointers at all. You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Use std::string,std::filesystem::path, std::chrono::year_month_day... And almost all your problems are gone. Using pointers requires expert quality and special problems.

The problem are these three lines:
string ffldr = df_fldr.string();
df.folder = new char[ffldr.length()];
df.folder = const_cast<char*>(ffldr.c_str());

The first line creates a local object, which will go out of scope and be destructed once the if (is_regular_file(i->path())) block ends.
The second line allocates memory for a string of ffldr.length() minus one characters, because C-style string character arrays needs space for a null-terminator character.
The third line overwrites the pointer you just created, loosing the memory you allocated. The pointer will also become invalid once the block ends, and the life-time of ffldr ends.
The natural C++ solution is of course to make DataFolder::folder a std::string.
If it can't be that for some reason, you first need to allocate ffldr.length() + 1 characters and use std::strcpy to copy the string.

df.name = new char[fn.length()]; df.name = const_cast<char*>(fn.c_str()); uses the same incorrect pattern a few lines above.

When const_cast finds its way into a program, it's usually a strong indicator that something bad is about to happen. Not always, but I'd say close to 100% of the time when it's written by someone without several years C++ experience.

@paddy I removed it. Using std::strcpy to copy the string now.

@RetiredNinja I fixed all the patterns where that code used.

@Some programmer dude used std::strcpy and allocated ffldr.length()+1 bytes to df.folder.
